# Is it possible to add values+symbols to an imported symbology in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, import, legend

I am trying to use an imported symbology from a layer file in ArcMap 10.2. However, the shapefile that I want to make a symbology for has two or three more values than are present in the imported legend. Whenever I want to add the new values and manually edit their symbols, the entire imported legend disappears and I end up with all new symbols.

Is it possible to add values and symbols to an imported legend?

I am using layer properties->categories->unique values in the layer properties window, same as in the layer file.

Answer (score 2):

Add the new values with the Add Values button, not the Add ALL Values button.  The add ALL values button will override the existing symbology and re-add all unique values whereas the Add Values button allows you to preserve the existing symbology and add new unique values not present in the Symbol list.

EDIT:
Also, confirm that after importing symbology from layer file, the count of symbols is greater than 0.  After import, you have to physically click the header to get the count.  If the count beside each symbol is 0 then the values in the source layer file do not match any values in your destination layer.
[image]

EDIT 2:

Based on our discussion, here is the process i recommend:

1. Import layer file and hit the count header to ensure matching values exist
   [image]
2. Click Add Values, Click the **Complete list** to ensure all possible values have already been added to symbology.  Type in new value in the text box and click Add to List
   [image]

3.Once new value appears in the list, select it and click OK in the dialog
[image]

4. New additional value is now added to the existing symbol list without altering any existing values
   [image]
5. Edit new value symbology as needed:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I was doing. When I click 'add values', the box does not show additional values. After clicking 'complete list', I get the three additional values, but when adding them, again, the imported symbology is gone.

Comment: After you import the layer file, click the "Count" heading in the Symbology list of the Symbology tab.  Is the cound beside each symbol greater than zero? (See screen capture above)

Comment: In the layerfile with the original legend it is, but in the new file certain labels do not contain polygons anymore. Of course I could manually adjust these labels to the three I need, that would solve the problem for now.

Comment: Yes you have to. IN order to add new values, the layer has to already contain those values.  Use the Add Values -> Add to List button to add non existing values. This way your original symbology is preserved and you can add new non-existing values. When editing and you add new features whose attributes match the new symbology they will inherit the newly created symbols.  Alternatively, and this is the better way, you can setup Sybtypes in the parent geodatabase.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you think I should add the values in the layerfile (where the symbology should come from) or in the shapefile? Because the values without a symbol are already present in the shapefile. I added the values in the layerfile (although there are no shapes with these values), but when importing it, the new symbols do not show.

Comment: You have to add any new symbology that does not yet match any existin features manually.  Import your layer file then Add Values -> Add to List -> Manually type the value and add to list.  This will create a new additional symbol in the list but there will be no features that match it until you create them.

Comment: I think there might be some miscommunication here: the new values already exist in the shapefile's attribute table, but not in the imported symbology.

Comment: Then you should be able to just hit "Complete List" in the dialog and those values should appear then add them to your symbology as I now explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought should happen, but the problem is it does not. I am sorry if my question was not clear. If it works this way for you, I must have missed a step somehow or something else is wrong.
I'll give it another go tomorrow and will let you know if it worked - I have to work on a different project now. Thanks for all your input!